# Docking and Anchoring is missing in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

i did not found the control's property called dock and anchor. if it is not there then how we can have the flavor of dock and anchor property of every control. here how could i set a controls dock property to Top. please discuss.

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

'Docking' in WPF can be done by Setting the HorizontalAllignment and the VerticalAllignment properties of a child control.

An alternative is nesting the control in a DockPanel and setting the DockPanel.Dock to e.g. Top on the control.l:

```
<DockPanel>
    <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Top" />
</DockPanel>
```

'Anchoring' in WPF can be done by setting the Margin on the child and/or the Padding on the container.

Answer (score 2):

i think you are getting at layout differences. The wpf framework works more on it's containers. take a look at this section for more help
http://www.wpftutorial.net/Layout.html

Answer (score 1):

check out [AvalonDock](http://avalondock.codeplex.com/releases/view/84100) on CodePlex, it's awesome and free!

here's a link to [getting started](http://avalondock.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=GettingStarted&referringTitle=Documentation)